# Autolayout Constraint Error

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a problem with autolayout contraints on my iPad project, when I rotate my device I have this error :

```
2013-06-03 13:16:24.969 PDFViewer[7534:907] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5525e0 H:[UIScrollView:0x1f551910]-(970)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f547740 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5525a0 H:|-(0)-[UIScrollView:0x1f551910]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f547740 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1f562520 h=--- v=--- H:[UIWindow:0x1f543890(768)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1f560af0 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x1f547740.width == UIWindow:0x1f543890.width>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5525e0 H:[UIScrollView:0x1f551910]-(970)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f547740 )>
```

Ok, some constraints are contentious but I don't set any constraint by myself, they are all set automatically in Interface Builder and I can't remove them. What I want is pretty simple, a scrollview, with fixed width and 100% height, and a collection view, with remaining width and 100% height.

Autolayout makes me crazy, any idea ?

Edit : Here are my constraints defined in IB

[image: IB Constraints]

Comment: Try `[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]`. [Read the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW167) for more details.

Comment: Thanks PartiallyFinite but it doesn't seems to change anything.

Comment: What about [this property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/requiresConstraintBasedLayout)?

Comment: You should also look through your constraints and make sure they don't conflict with each other. You have so many that there could be a fair chance that it's not possible to enforce two of them simultaneously. The reason you're getting the error is because it tries to enforce all the constraints that you defined and can't.

Comment: Yeah sure, there is a lot of constraints, but I can't delete them.

Comment: Ok, source of the problem found : it's this constraint     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5525e0 H:[UIScrollView:0x1f551910]-(970)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f547740 )>" but I still can't remove it, sor for now I just set the priority to 1 and I don't have this error anymore.

Comment: Take at look at [`NSLayoutPriority`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSLayoutPriorityRequired) to help you set the priorities of your constraints more meaningfully.

Comment: Also, if you solved your problem, post it as an answer so other people who have this problem can see your workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Error was caused by an automatic constraint, more precisely this one :

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f5525e0 H:[UIScrollView:0x1f551910]-(970)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f547740 )>",
```

As it is added by IB you can't delete it, so for ignoring it I have set the priority to 1.

[image: IB Priority]